# Linking Personal Close Reason to DoctorWhom's answer

Tags: feature-request, scope, close-reasons

Currently, our close reason for personal medical advice links to [this Meta question](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here)

However, DoctorWhom's great answer seems to be better suited. Can we alter the link of the close reason to this?

> For further information, this is [why we don't accept requests for personal medical advice](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212)

Comment: I support this :)  Should I make a TL;DR version at some point?

Comment: @DoctorWhom I wouldn't. There is no point of a  Too Long, Didn't Read, the whole answer should be read.

Comment: This change has been made. See this post and answer: https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1034/pma-close-reason-missing/1036?noredirect=1#comment5335_1036