# Standard comment situations: suggestions for close votes and down votes

Tags: discussion, comments

Downvotes and close votes should always be accompanied by a comment. While not strictly required as per SE policy this is especially important for new users. We should direct our criticism at bad or unwanted questions, not at unwanted users. Beginners – no matter how otherwise knowledgeable or qualified – make mistakes, that is to be expected.

Because there are a lot of similar situations, below is a list of comments that can be copy-and-pasted to provide new users more insight into how this site works and give reviewers a little help to save on keystrokes.

### Obviously, self-written comments are always favourable, but because we are lacking comments, here are a few suggestions that should provide a backbone for standard situations. These should not be copied blindly but preferably adapted to the individual case, if possible.

Comment: THANK YOU for doing this!!

Comment: Please test these and report back any problems! (If something borks up, comments can be speedily deleted… ;)

Answer (score 5):

### Answer *from new user* without backup – Requests for Sources

Rendered:

> Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE.  We work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta].  Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.

Plain-text:

```
Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. We work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.
```

Comment: There are two reliable resources posts. We should merge them?

Comment: @LangLangC I‘d just use the newer post which I have linked to here.

Comment: IMO: The newer post should be the base from where to integrate some of the older stuff. It's not perfect. The new one was mistaken at least once for a whitelist. The old one makes this explicitly not so and had recent activity. (BTW you also linked to the old one recently?)

Comment: Yeah, I had another comment that I usually paste before we updated the resources. I took updating that one as a reason to paste them here. BTW, if you have other recommendations, be sure to paste them too!

Comment: Maybe add "ask in chat"? But I am unsure how many of us visit regularly or are pinged if someone just drops by and posts. – Somehow this edit the post to comply might be handy and I am unsure whether the meta post makes it clear enough that links will rot and some content needs quotes for a large number of reasons.

Answer (score 4):

### Question – Welcome to *new users* and reminder that "Personal Medical Advice is off-topic" + immediate closevote

Rendered:

> Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor/748#748), we can not, and will not, give personal medical advice. If you have a question regarding your personal health, you should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/tour), visit the [How To Ask](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [MedicalSciences Meta](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/). I have voted to close this question and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explains question closure.

Plain-text:

```
Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212), we can not, and will not, give personal medical advice. If you have a question regarding your personal health, you should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta]. I have voted to close this question and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explains question closure.
```

Comment: Note that I included the tour, bad as it is. This should accomplish one thing alone, currently: See if the user is able and willing to follow instructions, visible to reviewers by earning that badge. Welcoming users is important but has its limits if they turn out stubborn.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE, [username]! [For a number of reasons outlined in this excellent post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212), we can not – and will not – give personal medical advice. If you have any question regarding your personal health, you should visit a GP or a specialist of your choice. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour] visit the [ask] page and [meta]. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explains question closure.

Comment: I checked, in theory, and above in praxis. Had even some chars left. – We might need another Welcome message for **lack of prior research/effort** That would burst the limit to include here. But what is worse? Personal advice!

Comment: I thought so. If you see errors regarding the links then go. Will do likewise in future. I am unsure if [username] is always expanded intelligently as well.

Comment: As a char saver we might adopt Graham's terms: "…see a doctor…" somehow. How widely known is the abbr "GP" (to non native speakers)? Also the specialist part is somehow quite specific and maybe even redundant for this?

Comment: I'd remove the [username] - it's not easy to add this on a phone which is how I do a lot work.

Comment: GP is common in western countries.  And this site is an english based site for english speakers.  We don't have to accommodate those who don't understand the language.

Comment: I've wondered this too - GP isn't as well known in the USA; although some people seem to know what it is, others don't. It isn't a specialty here.  Here FM and IM are generally the specialties that do primary care for adults, called a Primary Care Physician or Primary Medical Doctor. PCP or PMD.   I will probably stick with "doctor" or "primary doctor" or something.

Comment: I think they use FP instead of GP.

Comment: Cut and paste https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/15604/i-am-wolking-daily-5km-is-it-good-for-health  !  See how [username] is there!  Which is also why I suggested removing it.

Comment: @GrahamChiu It fits the character limit, because [tour] and [meta] are allowed shortcuts on main sites (but I had included them so that the rendering looks better). I fixed that problem.

Comment: I mean it exceeds the character limit when pasted into a comment for an actual question.

Comment: Here it doesn't. Try it on an actual post.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't.strange because it objected for me!

Comment: @GrahamChiu There might still be some trouble lurking somewhere. While I very much welcome further streamlining and shortening of these: where did you have this trouble? Narusan asked the same, I posted the suggestion-coment as it was in the example above (and would like to delete that comment now) as well as using it on main. By how many chars were you told to be off the mark? (And mobile or desktop) / (btw: Mobile and [username] I understand, but if on a full keyboard I think the username adds a nice touch to it.)

Comment: @LangLangC Tour before wasn’t [‘tour] but the whole link pasted in the plain-text. I edited it to replace that bug (initially it was indeed just [‘tour]). I suspect the mess up came from the fact that the tour needs to be linked for the rendering to work, and someone (might have been me) copied the adapted rendered text and forgot to delete the link.

Comment: I'll check the next time I need to use this comment!

Comment: Ok, I just tried it out now.  now has spare 3 characters!

Answer (score 3):

## Answer is basically nothing but a link/URL, but not SPAM

Rendered:

> Your link might or might not answer the question. However, [it would
>   be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for
>   reference. Please edit your answer to improve its quality. Thanks!

Plain-text:

```
Your link might or might not answer the question. However [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please edit your answer to improve its quality. Thanks!
```

Comment: I like this one.  Clear and straight to the point

Answer (score 3):

## Question – Lack of prior research effort + dubious assertions

> This question is not framed in the medical sciences. It is based on assumptions which are not made explicit, are not well-motivated (e.g., referenced), or are not held to be true within any of the research fields on-topic here. Please edit your question to provide more information on… (your research, why you are asking this question, what problems are you having understanding your research…)

Plain text:

```
This question is not framed in the medical sciences. It is based on assumptions which are not made explicit, are not well-motivated (e.g., referenced), or are not held to be true within any of the research fields on-topic here. Please edit your question to provide more information on… (your research, why you are asking this question, what problems are you having understanding your research…)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Question: medical advice question but potentially salvageable

Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! As currently phrased your question is [off-topic](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212), as it appears to be asking about personal health and will likely be closed. If you are able to rephrase it with the help of [How to Ask](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), removing all personal references, it might then be considered a suitable question. For [reasons mentioned here](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), we also require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*.

```
Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! As currently phrased your question is [off-topic](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212), as it appears to be asking about personal health and will likely be closed. If you are able to rephrase it with the help of [ask], removing all personal references, it might then be considered a suitable question. For [reasons mentioned here](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), we also require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Answer: more a comment rather than an answer or
Answer requesting further information from the OP

Rendered:

> This is really a comment and not an answer. Please register for an account. 
>   Once you earn sufficient reputation [you will be able to
>   post comments](//medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).
>   For the moment I've added this comment for you, and I'm flagging this
>   post for deletion.

Plain-text

```
This is really a comment and not an answer. Please register for an account. Once you earn sufficient reputation, [you will be able to post comments](//medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added this comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.
```

Comment: SE allows anonymous/unregistered posts in principle. It's easier to delete that part than to address it by hand if it's the case. If you know how to make it generic applicable to all situations: go on.

Answer (score 2):

## Question is about to be closed as a duplicate

This is tricky: duplicates *might* be a sign of lacking prior research.

*Make it clear that duplicates are a good thing: cross-linking sign posts to quality content*

> This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. In our model this [*not necessarily a bad thing.*](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)  If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Plain text:

```
This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. In our model this [*not necessarily a bad thing.*](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please [edit] it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1):

## Question from an old user (who should know better): A minimum level of self research is required.

See this [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188049/why-arent-the-rules-for-minimum-research-effort-being-enforced-consistently)

> We require some evidence demonstrating independent research of the problem domain has been conducted, and that you will also understand the answer.

or

> What are the results of your own research so far?

Up for edit ...

Comment: Important to get this one right! No edit, but a couple of suggestions: "Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. What has your own research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!"

Comment: Seems a little wordy :)

Comment: Yeah. Perhaps do not take all of it in. But as c&p that should not be such a problem. And: This is for newbies. In fact, strike that. I suggest using your terms *as is* for repeat offenders. I'll add the comment as another answer here for newbies. We should standardise the titles a bit though.

Comment: Just edit it in to the answer so we can edit it later on if necessary

Comment: Over on Psychology.SE (previously CogSci) we have a close reason set up for this purpose. (Lack of motivation shown).  Maybe the same or something similar could be set up here.  Better than 'question unclear'.

Comment: @Chris We clearly need a set of (exactly 3!) well thought out custom close reasons ("off-topic because…") to ease our lives. Are you up to open a meta question on this?

Comment: @LangLangC - I will do that now.

Answer (score 1):

## Question – Far Fetched

This question postulates a biologically implausible situation which can not be answered, and shows a lack of research into the problem domain.

up for edit.

Answer (score 1):

## Question: *New user* posting question lacking prior research

> Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

```
Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?
```

Comment: Over on Psychology.SE (previously CogSci) we have a close reason set up for this purpose. (Lack of motivation shown).  Maybe the same or something similar could be set up here.  Better than 'question unclear'.

Comment: Unless there's automatic variable substitution I don't think we should use [username] as it will inevitably get posted like that.

Answer (score 1):

### Question: Medical Advice for others

Rendered:

> Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748), we can not, and will not, give medical advice for any individual. Anyone who has a question regarding personal health, should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour), visit the [How To Ask](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [Health Meta](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com).  I have voted to close this question and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explains question closure.

Plain-text:

```
Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748), we can not, and will not, give medical advice for any individual. Anyone who has a question regarding personal health, should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta]. I have voted to close this question and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explains question closure.
```